# Node.js appears to be missing the multipart module

Tags: javascript, module, node.js, multipart

I am trying to parse form data, including upload files with a node.js http server. All of the tutorial type articles I have found use a `require("multipart");` to include the multipart module, but when I try the same I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'multipart'
```

I also can't find it in the current [api docs](http://nodejs.org/api.html) (though it is in the google cached version). So, has this module been removed from the standard installation or is there something else that does the job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Multipart.js is now [standalone module](http://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js/).

Answer (score 13):

There is a better multipart parser now.  You can find it at: http://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Answer (score 1):

Run a `cmd` window, there go to the folder that contains the files where you are trying to use the `multipart` module. Then, run the following command:

```
npm install multipart
```

That's all.