# need node.js module for mime multipart/related

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a node.js module that can generate and parse mime multipart/related http payloads. So far I've seen many modules focused on multipart/form-data so their api is very biased to handling fields etc. I need something more generic.

As an example, I need to generate/parse payload which may consist of 5 jpeg files without any form part.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644936/node-js-appears-to-be-missing-the-multipart-module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far, I haven't seen any complete solutions for multipart parsing/writing. Some options:

- [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) has some support for multi-part parsing
- There is also [multipart-parser](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/multipart-parser) for - well - multi-part parsing
- Writing multi-part data is somewhat trivial. Some tutorials:

  - [multipart/form-data uploads using node.js and http.request](http://onteria.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/multipartform-data-uploads-using-node-js-and-http-request/)
  - [Server side multipart/form-data uploads from nodejs](http://www.anandprakash.net/2011/10/20/server-side-multipartform-data-uploads-from-nodejs/)

Comment: thanks, I have written a parser based on one of the node-formidable modules, and I have written the parts by myself, as you also said. see here https://github.com/yaronn/ws.js/tree/master/lib/handlers/client/mtom

Comment: WOW Yaron, awesome work! Actually that whole `ws.js` looks pretty neat and I'm thinking I could be using it in a project! Do you have a license for it? I didn't find any remarks.

Comment: Does GNU GPL v3 work for you? If so you can use it based on this license and I will update the readme later on. If you prefer another license let me know

Comment: Nice! I would strongly prefer MIT since all the rest components I'm using are released under it. BSD is also fine. I think I could manage GPL v3 as well, but with more work. And whatever the license is I'd of course commit my changes back to you!

Comment: btw the page does not contain a lot of information about development, so feel free to drop me a mail (yaronn01@gmail.com) for any question or guidance, especially wrt unit tests. nodeunit is used for this.

Comment: Most of the libraries i've checked have dependencies like fs that requires node server side. Have you guys found a clean solution for client-side?

I'm just interested on parsing multipart/form-data or multipart/related on the clientside coming from a post xhrhttprequest or simliar. 
I must be missing something obvious. I still can't find good docs or examples about it. I even had the impression this had native support since ages in all major browsers since they handle seding multipart very easy. Almost everything refers to sending files instead of receiving multipart client-side

Comment: I'd like to know how to serve multipart/related contents from NodeJs server.