# multipart module is not visible to Node.js

Tags: node.js

I receive message: Could not find module 'multipart'.

This post [Node.js appears to be missing the multipart module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644936/node-js-appears-to-be-missing-the-multipart-module) helped to install it.

Error persists with the same message: Could not find module 'multipart'.

Any help appreciated.

P.S. I can see multipart module under nodejs installation directory.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually try to require the module?

Comment: `npm install multipart`? https://www.npmjs.org/package/multipart

Comment: `var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var multipart = require('multipart');` The code is listed immediately at the begging of the file.

Comment: lante, I did installed multipart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my script to multipart/test folder and updated

```
var multipart = require('multipart');
```

to

```
var multipart = require('../');
```

It works after all.